# Installing Net::LDAP on Strawberry Perl running on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, perl, cpan

I am attempting to install Net::LDAP on Strawberry Perl 64-bit (v5.26.2) without success. The command line 'cpanm' fails and points to a build.log.  It appears that files are not located where they are expected, leading me to think that some system environment variables are missing or have not been set to the correct directories. Subsequent searches for the 'missing' files are successful.

I also tried using the CPAN tool from the All Programs, and a standalone install and these failed in the PL2BAT.bat attempting to copy file from unknown directories.

Any ideas on how to set up the directory structure to work or system variables will be welcomed.

Build.log from CPANM

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7043 on perl 5.026002 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
Work directory is C:\Users\IBM_AD~1/.cpanm/work/1531317263.13328
You have make C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gmake.exe
You have LWP 6.33
Falling back to Archive::Tar 2.26
Searching install () on cpanmetadb ...
install is up to date. (0.01)
Searching Net::LDAP () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Net::LDAP
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MA/MARSCHAP/perl-ldap-0.65.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking perl-ldap-0.65.tar.gz
Entering perl-ldap-0.65
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Configuring perl-ldap-0.65
Running Makefile.PL
*** Module::AutoInstall version 1.03
*** Checking for Perl dependencies...
*** Since we're running under CPAN, I'll just let it take care
    of the dependency's installation later.
[Core Features]
- Test::More        ...loaded. (1.302135)
- File::Basename    ...loaded. (2.85)
- File::Compare     ...loaded. (1.1006)
- File::Path        ...loaded. (2.15)
- IO::File          ...loaded. (1.16)
- Text::Soundex     ...loaded. (3.05)
- MIME::Base64      ...loaded. (3.15)
- Convert::ASN1     ...loaded. (0.27 >= 0.2)
[IPv6 support]
- IO::Socket::INET6 ...loaded. (2.72)
[LDAPS support]
- IO::Socket::SSL   ...loaded. (2.056 >= 1.26)
[SASL authentication]
- Authen::SASL      ...loaded. (2.16 >= 2.00)
- Digest::MD5       ...loaded. (2.55)
- Digest::HMAC_MD5  ...loaded. (1.01)
- GSSAPI            ...missing.
==> Auto-install the 1 optional module(s) from CPAN? [n] n
[LDAP URLs]
- URI::ldap         ...loaded. (1.73 >= 1.1)
[Time conversion functions]
- Time::Local       ...loaded. (1.25)
[Read/Write DSML files]
- XML::SAX::Writer  ...missing.
- XML::SAX::Base    ...loaded. (1.09)
==> Auto-install the 1 optional module(s) from CPAN? [n] n
[Extended URL support when reading LDIFs]
- LWP               ...loaded. (6.33)
[LWP support for the LDAP protocol family]
- LWP::Protocol     ...loaded. (6.33)
- LWP::MediaTypes   ...loaded. (6.02)
- HTTP::Negotiate   ...loaded. (6.01)
- HTTP::Response    ...loaded. (6.16)
- HTTP::Status      ...loaded. (6.16)
- JSON              ...loaded. (2.97001)
*** Module::AutoInstall configuration finished.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Net::LDAP
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have JSON 0 ... Yes (2.97001)
Checking if you have File::Basename 0 ... Yes (2.85)
Checking if you have Time::Local 0 ... Yes (1.25)
Checking if you have LWP 0 ... Yes (6.33)
Checking if you have LWP::Protocol 0 ... Yes (6.33)
Checking if you have Text::Soundex 0 ... Yes (3.05)
Checking if you have URI::ldap 1.1 ... Yes (1.73)
Checking if you have Authen::SASL 2.00 ... Yes (2.16)
Checking if you have File::Compare 0 ... Yes (1.1006)
Checking if you have Digest::MD5 0 ... Yes (2.55)
Checking if you have Convert::ASN1 0.2 ... Yes (0.27)
Checking if you have Digest::HMAC_MD5 0 ... Yes (1.01)
Checking if you have Test::More 0 ... Yes (1.302135)
Checking if you have HTTP::Negotiate 0 ... Yes (6.01)
Checking if you have IO::File 0 ... Yes (1.16)
Checking if you have XML::SAX::Base 0 ... Yes (1.09)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have File::Path 0 ... Yes (2.15)
Checking if you have LWP::MediaTypes 0 ... Yes (6.02)
Checking if you have IO::Socket::INET6 0 ... Yes (2.72)
Checking if you have HTTP::Response 0 ... Yes (6.16)
Checking if you have MIME::Base64 0 ... Yes (3.15)
Checking if you have HTTP::Status 0 ... Yes (6.16)
Checking if you have IO::Socket::SSL 1.26 ... Yes (2.056)
Building and testing perl-ldap-0.65
cp lib/Bundle/Net/LDAP.pm blib\lib\Bundle\Net\LDAP.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/ldap.pm blib\lib\LWP\Protocol\ldap.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/ldapi.pm blib\lib\LWP\Protocol\ldapi.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/Assertion.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\Assertion.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/ASN.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\ASN.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/PersistentSearch.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\PersistentSearch.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/MatchedValues.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\MatchedValues.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/EntryChange.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\EntryChange.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/PostRead.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\PostRead.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/PasswordPolicy.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\PasswordPolicy.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/ManageDsaIT.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\ManageDsaIT.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Bind.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Bind.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/ldaps.pm blib\lib\LWP\Protocol\ldaps.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/Paged.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\Paged.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Constant.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Constant.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/DontUseCopy.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\DontUseCopy.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Entry.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Entry.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/VLV.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\VLV.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/SyncRequest.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\SyncRequest.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Examples.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Examples.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Entry.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Entry.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/ProxyAuth.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\ProxyAuth.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Extension/Cancel.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Extension\Cancel.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/Sort.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\Sort.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/DSML.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\DSML.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/Relax.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\Relax.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/PreRead.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\PreRead.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/VLVResponse.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\VLVResponse.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Extension/SetPassword.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Extension\SetPassword.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Extension/Refresh.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Extension\Refresh.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/SyncDone.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\SyncDone.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/SyncState.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\SyncState.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Extension.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Extension.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Control/SortResult.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Control\SortResult.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Schema.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Schema.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Extra.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Extra.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Search.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Search.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/FilterMatch.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\FilterMatch.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Extra/eDirectory.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Extra\eDirectory.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Intermediate/SyncInfo.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Intermediate\SyncInfo.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Extra/AD.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Extra\AD.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Filter.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Filter.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/LDIF.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\LDIF.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Extension/WhoAmI.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Extension\WhoAmI.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Reference.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Reference.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Schema.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Schema.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Message.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Message.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/LDIF.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\LDIF.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Message.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Message.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Security.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Security.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Search.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Search.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Intermediate.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Intermediate.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/FAQ.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\FAQ.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAP/RootDSE.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\RootDSE.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Filter.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Filter.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/RFC.pod blib\lib\Net\LDAP\RFC.pod
cp lib/Net/LDAPI.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAPI.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAP/Util.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAP\Util.pm
cp lib/Net/LDAPS.pm blib\lib\Net\LDAPS.pm
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/00ldif-entry.t t/01canon_dn.t t/02filter.t t/03schema.t t/04refloop.t t/05dsml.t t/06constant.t t/07filtermatch.t t/08time.t t/09ldif-http-url.t t/10ldif-controls.t t/40connect.t t/41populate.t t/42search.t t/43modify.t t/44schema.t t/45dse.t t/46ssl.t t/47ipc.t t/48url.t t/49lwp.t t/60cancel.t t/70sortctrl.t t/71preread.t t/72postread.t t/73assert.t t/74matchedvalues.t
Cannot detect source of 't/00ldif-entry.t'! at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/TAP/Parser/IteratorFactory.pm line 256.
    TAP::Parser::IteratorFactory::detect_source(TAP::Parser::IteratorFactory=HASH(0x2e8ee58), TAP::Parser::Source=HASH(0x2e1f1a8)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/TAP/Parser/IteratorFactory.pm line 211
    TAP::Parser::IteratorFactory::make_iterator(TAP::Parser::IteratorFactory=HASH(0x2e8ee58), TAP::Parser::Source=HASH(0x2e1f1a8)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/TAP/Parser.pm line 472
    TAP::Parser::_initialize(TAP::Parser=HASH(0x2e1f7c8), HASH(0x2aa7130)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/TAP/Object.pm line 55
    TAP::Object::new("TAP::Parser", HASH(0x2aa7130)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/TAP/Object.pm line 130
    TAP::Object::_construct(TAP::Harness=HASH(0x2d49348), "TAP::Parser", HASH(0x2aa7130)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/TAP/Harness.pm line 852
    TAP::Harness::make_parser(TAP::Harness=HASH(0x2d49348), TAP::Parser::Scheduler::Job=HASH(0x2e24680)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/TAP/Harness.pm line 651
    TAP::Harness::_aggregate_single(TAP::Harness=HASH(0x2d49348), TAP::Parser::Aggregator=HASH(0x2d471d0), TAP::Parser::Scheduler=HASH(0x2e1fb88)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/TAP/Harness.pm line 743
    TAP::Harness::aggregate_tests(TAP::Harness=HASH(0x2d49348), TAP::Parser::Aggregator=HASH(0x2d471d0), "t/00ldif-entry.t", "t/01canon_dn.t", "t/02filter.t", "t/03schema.t", "t/04refloop.t", "t/05dsml.t", ...) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/Test/Harness.pm line 136
    Test::Harness::_aggregate_tests(TAP::Harness=HASH(0x2d49348), TAP::Parser::Aggregator=HASH(0x2d471d0), "t/00ldif-entry.t", "t/01canon_dn.t", "t/02filter.t", "t/03schema.t", "t/04refloop.t", "t/05dsml.t", ...) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/Test/Harness.pm line 118
    Test::Harness::_aggregate(TAP::Harness=HASH(0x2d49348), TAP::Parser::Aggregator=HASH(0x2d471d0), "t/00ldif-entry.t", "t/01canon_dn.t", "t/02filter.t", "t/03schema.t", "t/04refloop.t", "t/05dsml.t", ...) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/Test/Harness.pm line 151
    Test::Harness::runtests("t/00ldif-entry.t", "t/01canon_dn.t", "t/02filter.t", "t/03schema.t", "t/04refloop.t", "t/05dsml.t", "t/06constant.t", "t/07filtermatch.t", ...) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/ExtUtils/Command/MM.pm line 72
    ExtUtils::Command::MM::test_harness(0, "inc", "blib\\lib", "blib\\arch") called at -e line 1
gmake: *** [Makefile:844: test_dynamic] Error 2
-> FAIL Installing Net::LDAP failed. See C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\.cpanm\work\1531317263.13328\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

Strawberry Perl was a vanilla install, nothing patched. If the install worked for you, then it must be something I customised in Windows. I will look at the Registry to see if something is incorrectly set.

Problem resolved by removing my additions to the PATH, and using Force to install.

Comment: What are the exact error messages?

Comment: That's a strange error, and I can't reproduce it here - Strawberry Perl Portable 5.26.2.1, and the same version of Net::LDAP installs cleanly. Is this a clean install of Strawberry Perl, not patched or anything?